# Django, could not serve a file to browser

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with django 1.6. I'm trying to save a file via a FileField model and then open it again to serve it to the browser. When trying to open the saved file, I can't access it, always getting 'NoneType' Error.

So this is how my code is made:

### Models:

```
class WB(models.Model):
    odt = models.FileField()
```

---

### View:

```
def save(request):
    ...
    #tmp.odt is generated befor
    tmp = File(open('files/tmp/tmp.odt', 'rb'))
    wb.odt.save("test.odt", tmp)
    tmp.close()
    ...
def display(request):
    odt = wb.odt.open(mode='rb')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text; charset=UTF-8')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='test.odt'
    #in the next line the error is thrown
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(odt.url)
    response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'
    response.write(odt)
    return response
```

---

### Traceback:

```
File "D:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.7-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
112.                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "D:\workspace\certwb\wb\views.py" in display
25.                 response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(odt.url)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /display/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working :D

Seems like I don't need to open the file, because its already open when accessing the model. So changing my view to the following  resolved the problem :D

### View

```
def: display(request):
    odt = wb.odt.file
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text; charset=UTF-8')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.odt"'
    response['Content-Length'] = odt.size
    response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'
    response.write(odt.read())
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `wb.odt.save("test.odt", tmp, save=False)`, when `save=True`(which is default) you also save the model after you save your file, which may not be what you want.